# In visual studio 2017 no option given to create xamarin forms project

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual studio 2017. It is not giving option to create new xamarin forms project.Then i reinstalled it then it is allowing me to create xamarin forms project.But today again there is no option is given to create new xamarin forms Project.While installation i selected mobile cross platform template ..
Not getting what is wrong in VS2017...Same is working well in VS 2015 which i was used previously ..I am sharing screenshots ....Please help[When Create new Project there is no option to select xamarin forms project) it is showing this popup[][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHcHF.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHcHF.png)
[image: When i click mobile App(Xamarin Forms) on start page this popup showing]
[image: When Create new Project there is no option to select xamarin forms project]

Comment: do you use stable version or preview version?

Comment: How would i get this info?It is Microsoft visual studio Enterprise 2017Version 15.6.4

Comment: Help--> about Microsoft visual studio, but if you already has just installed it ,I think it is gonna be stable version cause the current Preview is 15.7

Comment: I suggest that Try to reinstall only Cross-platform via installer